# Best way to check if today is the first of the month

Tags: php, date

I have 2 functions for checking if today is the first day of the month.
Does one of these have an advantage over the other, ie accuracy?

```
if(date('j', $timestamp) === '1') { }

if(date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-01')) { }
```

Comment: there are may ways to do most things

Comment: second method is slower, because you call date two times. accuracy is the same.

Comment: The second uses two conversions to strings, then compares resulting strings. That is considered a bad practice in my book.

Comment: Downvote was not needed. The question is not a duplicate. I'm not asking how to do it but if one holds an advantage.

Comment: hello sorry for comment in here where define variable of '$timestamp' i have similiar problem in here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375112/increase-field-in-mysql-every-early-month

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one does less checking I would use that.

You also don't need the timestamp argument if you want to check now / today